# Typo in the logout message

Tags: bug, status-completed, logout, grammar

When I log out I get this message: "You have **the** recently used the following credentials to login to your account:"

I believe the first "the" should be left out.

[image: Typo]

Comment: You are the quite observant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, changed this to

> You recently used the following credentials to login:

Answer (score 5):

> You are the quite observant. – [In silico](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/149668/in-silico)

This fix will go out with the next build.